# Connect another server on azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, namecheap

I have a website on the namecheap server and an application on microsft azure deploy on Azure App Service I would like to send post requests from my namecheap server to azure which contains the application my questionis this possible and also isn't there a security risk?

thank you for your help

Comment: Every web app is created with a publicly accessible endpoint. If you are utilizing HTTPS the traffic is encrypted between your client application and the web app. It would be helpful to understand what security risks you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Web programs are accessed through `HTTP Requests`. The security risk you mentioned does not exist.

In webapp, the security of web application data is what we need to care about.

**After passing the authentication**, the data can be `curd` according to the authority to ensure the security of the program.

It is recommended that you deploy the azure webapp program to increase the authentication function, such as [jwt token](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/).